# Python class Inheritance query

Tags: python, class, inheritance, compiler-errors, multi-level

I'm getting an error in python multilevel class inheritance.
This is my code:

```
class Animal():
    def __init__(self):
        print("Animal created")
    def whoAmI(self):
        print("Animal")
    def eat(self):
        print('eating')

class Dog(Animal):
    print("dog created")

class Cat(Dog):
    print("car created")

m = Cat()
Cat.eat()
```

This is the error I am getting:

[image]

Comment: I think you mean to have your Cat class inherit from Animal, not Dog

Comment: @Planet did my answer help you?

Comment: @TobiasWilfert thnks it helped me !

Comment: accepted @TobiasWilfert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
m = Cat()
m.eat()
```

`m` is an instance of class `Cat` and as such, you can call `eat()` on it. You cannot call eat on the `Cat` itself unless you say `Cat().eat()`.
This has little to do with inheritance as this code also gives you an error:

```
Animal.eat()
```

Also, cat should inherit directly from Animal and not dog.